# iAd fails to download with weird error

Tags: ios, iad

I all of a sudden get this out of `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:`

> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown error"
>   UserInfo={ADInternalErrorCode=102, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unknown
>   error, ADInternalErrorDomain=WebKitErrorDomain}

Does this have to do with a slow internet connection? I can't find a reference to the error code anywhere but I know for sure my current internet connection is very slow.

Comment: Did you try getting ads somewhere with a more reliable internet connection?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to such a connection right now! But will definitely see to that...

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find a reference to the error code anywhere

The error code `0` is exactly that, an `Unknown error`.

You may be receiving this error because you've set your iAd Testing Fill Rate to 0% on your development device.

Go to Settings>Developer>Fill Rate> and set it to 100%.

Comment: It's the connection.